# facebook php, post to page feed (not user feed)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have tried posting to a facebook page, using this call:

$facebook->call_api('/(pageID)/feed/', "post",array('message'=>"message here"));

however the message doesn't appear,
I have used the same code to post to a users wall, and it works without issue.
they both return an ID. and i don't get any auth errors.

Have I misunderstood the docs?
I have reread, and googled, so if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the page you're posting to only displays messages authored by the owner.  Does your message show up if you click on the "Just others" button on the Wall tab?

Comment: thats exactly what has happened. Thanks!